# /src/components/Form.js: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (59:0)

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hooks

After I added evaluation to my form

```
const Form = ({
  valid,
  setValid,
  setStatus,
  inputText,
  setInputText,
  todos,
  setTodos
}) => {
  const inputTextHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setInputText(e.target.value);
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
if(inputText){

    setTodos([
      ...todos,
      { text: inputText, completed: false, id: Math.random() * 1000 }
    ]);
    setInputText(""); 
  } else {
setValid(false)
  };
  
  const onStatusChange = (e) => {
    setStatus(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <form>
    <input
      value={inputText}
      onChange={inputTextHandler}
      type="text"
      className="todo-input"
    />

    {!valid && <span className="error">Please enter a todo</span>}
    <button onClick={onSubmit} className="todo-button" type="submit">
      <i className="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
    </button>
    <div className="select">
      <select onChange={onStatusChange} name="todos" className="filter-todo">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="completed">Completed</option>
        <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
  
  );
  };


export default Form;
```

I get the following error:

> SyntaxError
> /src/components/Form.js: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (59:0)

I´ve tried to find my misstake, without luck
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/todo-forked-zsrgh)

Hope you can find my mistake
Thanks in advance
/ Peter

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing curly brace on line 29 of `Form.js`.

```
import React from "react";

const Form = ({
  valid,
  setValid,
  setStatus,
  inputText,
  setInputText,
  todos,
  setTodos
}) => {
  const inputTextHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setInputText(e.target.value);
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (inputText) {
      setTodos([
        ...todos,
        { text: inputText, completed: false, id: Math.random() * 1000 }
      ]);
      setInputText("");
    } else {
      setValid(false);
    }
  }; // Missing curly brace
  const onStatusChange = (e) => {
    setStatus(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        value={inputText}
        onChange={inputTextHandler}
        type="text"
        className="todo-input"
      />

      {!valid && <span className="error">Please enter a todo</span>}
      <button onClick={onSubmit} className="todo-button" type="submit">
        <i className="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
      </button>
      <div className="select">
        <select onChange={onStatusChange} name="todos" className="filter-todo">
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="completed">Completed</option>
          <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```